# Blender 2.77 no longer orbits around the z axis when using scroll wheel or numpad 6, 4?

Tags: 3d-view

Does anyone have this problem and know how to fix it? I am used to being able to rotate around the global z with the number pad or using scrollwheel + ctrl + alt, without regard to which way my camera was currently facing. It is a habit formed over the last 10 years of blender use, and was a quick way to single out parts of a mesh when working. Now however, this appears to rotate around the viewport why (IE, it rotates around an imaginary fixed line drawn from the center top to center bottom of the viewport.) This change is really throwing off my work, and I have ground to a complete halt since installing blender 2.77 an hour ago.

Edit: Things I have tried so far, with no change:

- Re-installing
- Resetting to Factory
- Switching Orbit from Turntable to Trackball

  (I think the problem is that I am stuck in Trackball for some reason, but not sure.)

Comment: I think there was a design change in 2.77 that is going to be reverted to the old behavior in a soon-to-be-released 2.77a. See https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/rc

Comment: @jrboddie, thank you! I hope they make this an option, rather than a "my way or the highway" type fix. Ten years of habit is hard to break. is there any way to find out when revision "a" will be released?

Comment: [This was considered a feature](https://youtu.be/kY51pu6r4xA?t=6m36s), but it's understandable why some are against it. On a related note, [trackpad rotation of the Viewport has been changed as well](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49602/how-to-get-the-old-trackpad-behavior-back-in-2-77) and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

That's a new [feature](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/UI#Other_Improvements):

> The View3D NumPad4/6 keys have no more a 'turntable' type of rotation, but (as all other rotating numpad keys) use a view axis (the vertical one, see [T47263](http://developer.blender.org/T47263) and [rBfe0ca82b232d](http://developer.blender.org/rBfe0ca82b232d)).

As it caused some confusion, the developers for now [reverted](https://developer.blender.org/rB72199882587b20b7b72b5205cb84372fdc8da12c) this new behaviour in 2.77a, so you should just [update](https://www.blender.org/features/2-77/).

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious but you could just set the center of the viewport to the object you are working on by pressing <kbd>Num .</kbd>

Hopefully they will fix it in a future version but until then this might be the only way.