# Can the viewport rotation be changed?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I had just upgraded from using blender version 2.75 to 2.77 and I immediately found a difference between the two. Here are the differences:

[image]

default perspective 2.75

[image]

default for 2.77

When I do a custom rotation using the same coordinates, the view becomes different.

[image]
2.75

[image]
2.77

In 2.77 it's no longer rotating directly along the z-axis.

How can I rotate the viewport on the z-axis in 2.77 as it was on 2.75 (or 2.76?)

Comment: To rotate the view press Shift and Ctrl while scrolling the mouse wheel.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-roll-the-viewport

Comment: Set the scene however you'd like it to start, and press **Ctrl+U** to save it as default. From them on blender will open with the settings you created. read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43877/set-all-panels-to-be-closed-by-default-or-remember-settings-by-file/43902#43902

Comment: I found the answer to my problem: [the turntable isn't working in 2.77 but was corrected in 2.77a](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49773/blender-2-77-no-longer-orbits-around-the-z-axis-when-using-scroll-wheel-or-numpa)

Answer (score 0):

Different screenshot would be useful in your question, specifically screenshots with an expanded properties shelf (<kbd>T</kbd> key) in each version. My starting guess is that the models shown in the two versions may not have identical rotation settings to start with, in which case applying the rotation might resolve this issue.